# In Python, is there a better way to deal with command line options when each option could have several arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I've a Python app like this:

```
$ app.py -a arg1 -a arg2 -b file1.b -b file2.b
```

Depending on the option, in app.py, I use two different functions to process the input files. As each option can have several file arguments, I would like something like this:

```
$ app.py -a arg1 arg2 -b *.b
```

After searching on the net, I find these three modules: getopt, argparse, optparse

And I wrote a simple one for my app:

```
optionDict= {'-a':aFunction, '-b':bFunction}
for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
    if arg in optionDict: # arg is an option here.
        funcName = optionDict[arg]
    else: # arg is not an option, then it's a fileName. Deal with this file with the function found according to previous arg.
        funcName(arg)
```

My quesion: Are there any other modules or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since 2012 Python has an easy, powerful and very cool module for argument parsing called [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt). It works with Python from 2.5 to 3.3 and needs no installation. Here is the code for your particular case:

```
'''app.py

Usage:
  app.py -a ARG ... -b FILE ...
  app.py (-h | -v) 

'''
from docopt import docopt
args = docopt(__doc__, version='1.0')
# now do something based on the value of args dict
```

So this is it: one line of code plus your doc string which *is* essential. I told you it's cool -- didn't I ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you found `argparse` to be too hard to get started with because of the complexity, then you would probably like `plac` which is available on PyPi. It is a wrapper around argparse which hides the complexity, and it takes care of a lot of boilerplate argument checking for you.

It works for both Python 2 and 3, and has a decorator that allows Python 2 users to get access to a nice Python 3 feature for function parameters. And you can even nest commands in one another so that you could have -arguments (beginning with dash) and .arguments (beginning with dot) on one command line.

Here are the docs http://plac.googlecode.com/hg/doc/plac.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that argparse is the way to go. It does a great job, it is easy to use and in the standard library since 2.7. Take a look a the nargs argument. From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html)

Fixed elements to consume

> > > parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> > >       parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2)
> > >       parser.add_argument('bar', nargs=1)
> > >       parser.parse_args('c --foo a b'.split())
> > >           Namespace(bar=['c'], foo=['a', 'b'])

One arg will be consumed from the command line if possible, and produced as a single item. If no command-line arg is present, the value from default will be produced

> > > parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> > >       parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='c', default='d')
> > >       parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='?', default='d')
> > >       parser.parse_args('XX --foo YY'.split())
> > >           Namespace(bar='XX', foo='YY')
> > >       parser.parse_args('XX --foo'.split())
> > >           Namespace(bar='XX', foo='c')
> > >       parser.parse_args(''.split())
> > >           Namespace(bar='d', foo='d')

All command-line args present are gathered into a list.

> > > parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
> > >       parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='*')
> > >       parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='*')
> > >       parser.add_argument('baz', nargs='*')
> > >       parser.parse_args('a b --foo x y --bar 1 2'.split())
> > >           Namespace(bar=['1', '2'], baz=['a', 'b'], foo=['x', 'y'])